# Teams Toolkit / Bot Framework: Adaptive card action works but generates "Unable to reach app. Please try again."

Tags: c#, botframework, teams-toolkit

In my TeamsActivityHandler I override `OnInvokeActivityAsync()` to react to action buttons in an adaptive card:

```cs
protected override async Task<InvokeResponse> OnInvokeActivityAsync(ITurnContext<IInvokeActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var actionId = ((JObject)turnContext.Activity.Value)["action"]["id"].ToString();

        switch (actionId)
        {
            case "action_execute_query":
                await SendResponse("This feature is currently not implemented.", turnContext);
                return CreateInvokeResponse();

            default:
                return await base.OnInvokeActivityAsync(turnContext, cancellationToken);
        }
    }
```

I can see the code works without error (notice how the text response is successfully displayed), however Teams always adds the message "Unable to reach app. Please try again.":

[image]

`SendResponse()` is a simple helper:

```cs
async Task SendResponse(string response, ITurnContext turnContext)
    {
        Activity responseActivity = MessageFactory.Text($"{response}");
        await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(responseActivity);
    }
```

Ngrok does not report any errors.

The card's JSON for the actions looks like this:

```json
"actions": [
    {
      "type": "Action.Execute",
      "title": "Execute",
      "id": "action_execute_query",
      "tooltip": "Execute the query and show results",
      "verb": "execute_query",
      "data": {
        "msteams": {
          "type": "task/submit"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Action.Execute",
      "title": "Reset",
      "id": "action_reset",
      "tooltip": "Reset the conversation and start over",
      "verb": "reset",
      "data": {
        "msteams": {
          "type": "task/submit"
        }
      }
    }
  ],
```

How can I get rid of this error message?